# How do I do "save target as" in google chrome? Or firefox?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser

One of the right mouse click options in windows explorer is "save target as" how do I do the same thing in google chrome or firefox?

Or at least how do I stop certain file-types (e.g., mp3, pdf) from automatically downloading

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Chrome it's called "Save link as..." on OS X and what it does is ask you where to download the file.

[image]

There's another option to ask you before the download of each file, just tick the box at the bottom:

[image]

Comment: cheers, i'd assumed that just saved the link url, it seems to do what i want

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + Left click does the same as selecting "Save Target As...".

Or use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to select the link and then <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>. It does the same as selecting "Save Target As...".

Comment: Trying this on Opera (that is Chromium-based) does nothing - at least when the "Ask where to save..." checkbox is unchecked. Petty... I guess it's the same in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Both previous answers are wrong.  Left click opens the targeted file instead of saving it, and  "save link as" only does just that...saves the link...not the file.  In short there is nothing comparable to "save target as" in Chrome.

Comment: "Save link as" saves the file the link points to. For example, saving the link <http://www.google.com> saves Google's search page to a file.

Comment: @Pat, you were downvoted because your answer was not correct. It's perfectly acceptable to edit your answer to improve it when someone points out a problem.